# How to filter model array based on specific property

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I have a model class which contain these properties:-

```
class ItemModel:NSObject{
   var itemName:String?
   var itemPrice:String?
   var itemCategory:String?
   var isAvailable:Bool?
}
```

I have an array of type `ItemModel` Class

```
var itemArray = [ItemModel]()
```

I want to filter this array based on `itemCategory`

Comment: Why are all your model's properties optional? Does it make sense to have an item without a name, price, category or availability? Also do you really need to inherit from `NSObject`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
let filteredArray = self.originalArray.filter({($0.itemCategory.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))!})
```

Comment: thanks its working

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like:

```
itemArray.filter({$0.itemCategory == "Test"})
```

$0 will present the object in the array and you can use it for every property in your object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

`self.yourArrayList.filter({$0. itemName == xyz})` like this

Inside {} you need to put your condition for filtering

Answer (score 0):

Use filter to do that:

```
itemArray.filter({$0. itemCategoty == "abc"})
```